# ruby toUnicode fun does not return the idn site when there is no www. in the url

Tags: ruby, idn

In my rails app, i convert a idn url to punycode and back to idn.

But if i have a url like this [http://日本語.jp](http://%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E.jp) (without www.)

```
domain = "http://日本語.jp"
punycode = Idna.toAscii(domain)  => http://xn--blagzdfd.com
```

but trying to convert it backto IDN fails

```
 idn = Idna.toUnicode(punycode) =>        xn--blagzdfd.com instead of http://日本語.jp
```

the toUnicode converts back properly if we just add www. to the above idn url like [http://www.日本語.jp](http://www.%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E.jp)

am i missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out. the problem was the http part in the url. the toUnicode fun works fine. if we remove the http part in the url and pass it.